# Каждые 5 секунд создавать и запускать случайное число потоков от 1 до 6

Tags: java, многопоточность

Ребята подскажите плз как каждые 5 секунд создавать и запускать случайное число потоков от 1 до 6.

Comment: а что должен делать работающий поток?

Comment: Каждый поток должен вызывать метод acquire() у объекта семафора и после этого выводить 
в консоль сообщение "Th Acquire" + counter,

Comment: Я просто не могу понять как создать случайное число потоков)

Comment: Генерировать случайное число, а далее цикл.

Comment: Ох ну спасибо... я знаю как генерировать случайные числа, я не знаю как внедрить так что бы создавались потоки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь используется `ScheduledExecutorService`, чтобы назначить время, через которое будет повторяться код.

```java
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,7);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            //ваш код
        }).start();
    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Можно и собственный таймер сделать.

```java
new Thread(() -> {
    while(true) {
        int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,7);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                //ваш код
            }).start();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Но тут вопрос в том, нужно вам, чтобы ваш код выполнялся каждые пять секунд или через пять секунд, если через, то первые два варианта, а если каждые, то нужно использовать `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate()` (как в первом примере) или `Timer` и `TimerTask`:

```java
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {//schedule(), если через
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,7);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                //ваш код
            }).start();
        }
    }
},0,5000);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь разобрался )

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь ну вроде я уже и сам разобрался.
Вот как  создавать рандомное число потоков:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    public MyThread(String s){
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run" + getName());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random()*6);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        MyThread mt = new MyThread(" T " + i);
        mt.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: При использовании многопоточности лучше использовать `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,7)` для генерации случайных чисел.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать )